# Astrill VPN reports "Could not load SSL library" on login

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, ssl

I'm trying to get the Astrill VPN 32-bit v3.2 application working on Ubuntu xenial 16.04.3.

On trying to login, I get a message saying "Could not load SSL library".

Astrill support's only suggestion is to uninstall, reboot and reinstall the application, which has not helped.

I've also tried installing the i386 version of openssl, which hasn't helped either.

What else could I look at to try and resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make sure you have openssl installed. You will need version 1.0 since Astrill does not support 1.1. To install `1.0.2`, run

```
sudo apt install openssl=1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.8
```

Then install shared libraries, first check which version you want by running `apt-cache search libssl | grep SSL`. Example output:

```
libssl-dev - SSL development libraries, header files and documentation
libssl-doc - SSL development documentation documentation
libssl1.0.0 - SSL shared libraries  <-- version number
```

Install the library with the correct version:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0
```

From the conversation in the comments, you also need to install `libssl-dev`, again, make sure the version is 1.0.

```
sudo apt install libssl-dev=1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.8
```

It is possible you need to install the packet `ca-certificates` as well.

---

If the above did not solve the problem, open the file `/etc/ld.so.conf` as `sudo` and add a new line at the end

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openssl-1.0.0
```

Dependin on yuor system, the path could be different. Two other locations to try are `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/lib/openssl-1.0`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44282009/7579547) and [here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/astrill/).

Then run `sudo ldconfig`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried all the above including the alteration to `/etc/ld.so.conf` without success. Could this be an issue with Python 2 vs Python 3? I notice that I have openssl in both python2.7 and python3.5

Comment: @xiuyuan What version of openssl are you using? I saw [here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/astrill/) that you need openssl-1.0. Astrill can't use 1.1. For the python issue, I haven't seen anything about it. I guess if you have both installed it should be fine. You can also try this path: `usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openssl-1.0.0`.

Comment: I was on openssl 1.1. I tried downgrading to 1.0 with `sudo apt install openssl=1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.6` and confirmed with `openssl version`, but still have the same error from Astrill.

Comment: @xiuyuan Did you try adding `usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openssl-1.0.0` to `/etc/ld.so.config` and run `sudo ldconfig` afterwards? If that path doesn't work, try with `usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`. Also, you can try checking the shard libraries (in hte answer above) after the downgrade of openssl.

Comment: @xiuyuan The path could be a bit different as the path above is version 1.0.0.

Comment: The path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openssl-1.0.0` does seem to be correct as I can see the files there. Adding it to `/etc/ld.so.conf` does not help though; I've tried it with the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the Astrill application.

Comment: @xiuyuan You ran `sudo ldconfig` after adding the path as well? Did you check if you need to downgrade the `libssl` library? Maybe you can install the `libssl-dev` as well, can't hurt to try.

Comment: Success! It seems I also needed `sudo apt install libssl-dev=1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.8`. Now it works. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @xiuyuan No problems :)

Answer (score 3):

Following Hugh's comment on Shaido's answer, simply installing `libssl-dev` solved the problem.

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```